# Is it less secure to return CSRF token in response body vs response cookie (header)?

Tags: javascript, express, security, cross-domain, csrf

### Is it any less secure to return a csrf-token via res.json(), than returning via res.cookie()?

My project configuration is set as follows:

Domains:

```
front-end:  "https://front.domainA.com"    // AWS Amplify, React
back-end:   "https://back.domainB.com"     // AWS Amplify, Express.js
```

---

### Further details

Please note that I've tested sharing cookies across localhost ports (front-end: 3000, back-end :5000) with no problems.

That said, now that my app is on real-world domains, it's no longer allowing to read cookies from generated from another domain.  I've created a separate post in regards to that question.  [You can read it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63945958/can-third-party-cross-domain-cookies-be-accessed-read-by-javascript).  Please reply in that thread if you have answers to that question.

Because of this, I am looking at returning my CSRF-Token in the *response body*, as so:

```
static async csrfToken(req, res, next) {
    console.log("catching waves...");

    return res.status(200).json({ "csrf-token": req.csrfToken() });
}
```

Instead of a *cookie in the response header*, like so:

```
static async csrfToken(req, res, next) {
    console.log("catching waves...");

    res.cookie("csrf-token", req.csrfToken(), {
        secure: true,
        sameSite: "none",
    });
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "We be surfing!" });
}
```

So back to my original question.

### Is it less secure to return a CSRF-Token in a *response body*? And is there any downside for doing that as opposed to returning in a cookie?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: What happens to the csrf token when it is received in a request? How is it checked?

Comment: @GaborLengyel, I request via: const token = await axios.get('/csrf-token').   Then return from express via: res.json({ 'csrf-token': xxxx}).   And then just store the variable in localstorage.   I can encrypt it in localstorage and decrypt before attaching to all req.headers.   Or I can leave the plain token in localStorage and sign it with JWT before attaching it to all req.headers.   If I use the sign method, I think I could just verify the signature on the backend before passing the token to csurf.  That way, if an attacker gots hold of the plain token, it will not work unverified.